# Incremental Adding of New Categories

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, classification, decision-tree

I was wondering if there is any algorithm for incrementally adding new classes to existing classifier system. For e.g. if I have trained a system with 50 categories, and I want to add another 10 categories to the system, what methods should I look into? There are wide range of algorithms that allow incrementally updating system with additional training samples from existing categories, but I am not aware of methods that will allow adding more categories. Theoretically, I think Nearest Neighbor like algorithms can be applied to this task, but are there other algorithms that are suitable for large scale tasks (say updating a system trained with 500 categories with 50 additional categories? May be in the domain of incremental decision trees? Algorithms like incremental SVM do not scale very well for large number of categories. If there is any paper/code I would appreciate pointers to it.

Comment: you mean clustering, not classification, right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking about divisive clustering (you have a given set of data and want to re-cluster them with a larger number of groups than before).

Most algorithms I'm familiar with would require re-building the clustering basically from scratch. However, you might want to look at the BIRCH algorithm. Since it stores only a summary of the classes (without explicit data references), it is a) suitable for Big Data™, and b) it features a kind of distance measure that might tell you which category you should split next (in case you want to dynamically generate additional 50 "most distinct" categories).